# Solving a recurrence relation using homogeneous+particular solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

A simple recursion:

$a_{n+1} - a_n = 2n +3 , n \ge 0 , a_0 = 1 $

I can solve this by simply writing out multiple lines, and deducing that $a_n = (n+1)^2 , n \ge 0 $

However, I would like to solve this using two other methods:

1. Solving for the homogeneous, solving for a particular, and combining.
2. Solving using generating functions.

My attempts at both have been very unsuccessful. In particular, I would really like to learn the first method on this equation.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Solving for the homogeneous, solving for a particular, and combining."?

Comment: I assume the recursion = 0. Also, solving for the homogeneous equation is clear, don't worry.

Comment: @Kaynex Sorry! Typo in the post. I've updated the equation, the recursion = 2n + 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve for the homogeneous equation, remove any term that doesn't have an "a" in it:
$$a_{n+1} - a_{n} = 0$$
A homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients has a typical solution method. Let $a_n = C*λ^n$, where C is any constant:
$$C*λ^{n+1} - C*λ^{n} = 0$$
Divide both sides by $C*λ^n$:
$$λ - 1 = 0$$
$$λ = 1$$

### As such, the homogeneous solution is $a_n = C*1^n = C$

Now, we want to solve for the non-homogeneous solution. We want to find the solution to:
$$a_{n+1} - a_{n} = 2n + 3$$
We essentially do this by educated guessing. Since the right side is of the form An + B, we would let $a_n = An + B$. However, if you try it, you'll find it doesn't work. So, the next guess is to let $a_n = An^2 + Bn + C$:
$$A(n + 1)^2 + B(n + 1) + C - An^2 - Bn - C = 2n + 3$$
$$2An + A + B = 2n + 3$$

You can set up a system of equations to equate the coefficients, but in this case it's pretty simple. $A = 1, B = 2$ Putting that back into our original guess tells us:

### The non-homogeneous solution is $a_n = n^2 + 2n$

This is the easiest part. The general solution is the sum of both solutions.

### The general solution is $a_n = n^2 + 2n + C$

Where C is any constant. Then, you can find your specific solution by plugging in your point and solving for C.